# Manipulate YouTube video list from json

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, youtube-api

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

            // The unique video id of the youtube video (can be obtained from video url)
            youtube_url = "bdB_CL-daxA" ;

            playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
            playerView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);



    }
```

Currently I have the above. I want to manipulate video list without updating the app. Indirectly I want to show YouTube videos from json data!
So how can i ?

Comment: use youtubeplayerview or youtubeplayerfragment

Comment: @DivyeshPatel how? Any tutorial link to?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/tree/master/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo

Comment: @DivyeshPatel thank u